# woocommerce customer Fetch with time filter

Tags: rest, woocommerce

I am requesting customer data using Rest Api of woocommerce. Woocommerce api documentation says
"All endpoints (except for customer orders) support date filtering via created_at_min and created_at_max as ?filter[] parameters. e.g. ?filter[created_at_min]=2013-12-01".

However, when I am giving date filter in request URL it results in blank response!!

My question is,can the customer data be fetched via date filter in woocommerce.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass Filter with time in REST API of WooCommerce.

Just pass the filter in H:i:s format.

Note : while trying to generate the signature, I found, the URL encoding needs to be done twice because of extra space between DateTime filter criteria. Just encode the clean text once to get RFC3986 encoding, and do it again to generate the signature. Pass the first encoded string and append the generated signature. I saw the filter to be working.